pg_dump & pg_restore files on windows has 0 bytes size
I had installed DBeaver CE 24.1.1.202406231636 on a laptop running  windows 11 64 bits.
I am using to manage a little database running in PostgreeSQL 16.3 in Ubuntu 22.04
I have been trying to make a backup of my datbase using DBeaver installed on my laptop (windwos 11 64bits) but I got the bellow error everytime I try to back it up:
Error executing process
  Cannot run program "C:\Users\pm25383\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers\clients\postgresql\win\15\pg_dump.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\pm25383\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers\clients\postgresql\win\15"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido
  Cannot run program "C:\Users\pm25383\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers\clients\postgresql\win\15\pg_dump.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\pm25383\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers\clients\postgresql\win\15"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido
    CreateProcess error=193, %1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido
    CreateProcess error=193, %1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido

What I saw, is the pg_dump.exe file has 0 bytes on that directory:
C:\Users\pm25383\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers\clients\postgresql\win\15\pg_dump.exe

so, it seems it is corrupted or it was wrongly installed, but I am able to use DBeaver as normal, to create / drop / update tables, views, keys and running script to update data on tables.
Does anyone help to fix the issue? I dont know how to fix it.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have been browsing on the web but not found any relevant information yet

It seem the pg_dump is 15,and you pg server is 16.You should use the same version or higher.
